# how to create array of objects from 2 different array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have 2 arrays with different lengths and the number of items in each array is dynamic. I want to merge these 2 arrays and have the finalArray as an output. How can I do that?
I want to add each item in array1 to all objects of array2 as key and an empty array as value.

```
 const array1 = [7665,7666]
 const array2 = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user-1",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user-2", 
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "user-3",
},
  ]

 const finalArray = [
    {
      7665: [],
      7666: [],
      users: 'user-1',
    },
    {
      7665: [],
      7666: [],
      users: 'user-2',
    },
    {
      7665: [],
      7666: [],
      users: 'user-3',
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've used as a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't really understand this question - do you want to merge both arrays? Add some explanation in your question as well as your code, and your research effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen: Yes,I wanted to merge them. one of answers solve my problem

Comment: @ElhamBagheri Next time, try to explain your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const array1 = [7665, 7666];
const array2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user-1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user-2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "user-3",
  },
];

const result = array2.map(({ id, name }) => ({ 
  ...array1.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ 
    ...acc, 
    [cur]: [] 
  }), {}), 
  users: name 
}))

console.log(result)
```

The map creates one object per user from array2. The reduce converts each number in array1 to a key on the final user object.